# Does javascript export references or deep copies of objects?

Tags: javascript

```
const obj = {A: 2}
module.exports = obj
```

If another module imports from the above module, will it get a deep copy of `obj` or just a reference?

Comment: also [Does module.require(...).* return a copy of module.exports.* or a reference of it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13346046/does-module-require-return-a-copy-of-module-exports-or-a-reference-of-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exports work exactly the same way as every other way of passing values around.

The value of `obj` is a reference to the object.

A copy of that value (still a reference) is assigned to `exports`.

Anything `require`ing that module will get a copy of that value (still a reference).

Comment: isn't that dangerous? What if an importer modifies the object? Then that will modify it for every other importer? How to export a deep copy?

Comment: "Then that will modify it for every other importer?" — Yes. This can be useful.

Comment: "How to export a deep copy?" — Export a factory function instead of a plain object.

Answer (score 1):

I would say references because modules have their own execution context. meaning they track state of the context as you import / re import it.

He is an article that explain it better.
https://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/javascript-module-system-for-state-management